# Submenu Arrow Not Showing on Mobile

Tags: css, shopify, parallax

The menu on our [homepage](https://bloomthis.co) has an issue where sometimes the submenu arrow is not displayed on mobile. This prevents user from seeing the multiple pages in the submenu; clicking where the arrow would be brings me to the main menu page (i.e. "Shop", "Christmas", etc.). It's been very inconsistent - reloading the page occasionally helps but it could take multiple refreshes.

[image: Homepage menu on mobile]

I viewed the homepage on desktop (Chrome device mode) to reproduce the issue but haven't been successful. The CSS for the arrow is below:

> .mm-list a.mm-subopen {
>       width: 40px;
>       height: 100%;
>       padding: 0;
>       position: absolute;
>       right: 0;
>       top: 0;
>       z-index: 2; }

I tried commenting out `right: 0` which caused the arrow and text to overlap. So far this was the only "stable" thing - the arrow shows up every time I load the page on mobile.

I'm using OnePlus 3T Chrome but issue is also reported on Samsung S9, not sure if it's device-specific.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

pls try this css :

```
.mm-list a.mm-subopen {
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: With the code above, the submenu arrow doesn't show at all but it creates a blank row that occupies the whole hamburger menu width.

<img src="https://imgur.com/a/ubDpFjz" width="394" height="700">

Clicking anywhere on the empty space (1) and (2) expands the submenu.